# Kubernetes Ingress for same host in different namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have two services, `tea` and `coffee`, each is in their own namespace, I would like `domain.com` to go to the `tea` service and `domain.com/coffee` to go to `coffee`.

As each is in a namespace I have had to make two pieces of ingress, but when I try to apply them I get the error `MAPPING   Path '/coffee' already defined in another Ingress rule`.

My two pieces of ingress look like the following:

Tea:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain.com
    secretName: tea-tls
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: tea
          servicePort: 80
```

and Coffee:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: coffee
  namespace: coffee
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain.com
    secretName: coffee}-tls
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /coffee
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /coffee/*
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem isn't having tea and coffee, but defining the `coffee` path twice in the coffee ingress. According to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout I would assume that you only need the `/coffee` path, and can delete the `/coffee/*` path.

Answer (score -5):

According to https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17088, the voyager ingress controller can do the trick. Example (taken from the link):

```
apiVersion: voyager.appscode.com/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: foo
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: s1.bar # serviceName.Namespace
          servicePort: '80'
```

Comment: Does the app have to be in the same namespace as the ingress-controller ?

Comment: Error: Failed to update Ingress default/prebid-server because: Ingress.extensions "prebid-server" is invalid: spec.rules[0].http.backend.serviceName: Invalid value: "prebid-server.prebid": a DNS-1035 label must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters or '-', start with an alphabetic character, and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'my-name',  or 'abc-123', regex used for validation is '[a-z]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?')